# After clicking a link and loading a new page how can I then run a function?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a Hybrid app using cordova and currently when users use the search function a list of clickable search results return with the users search query highlighted in each result. The problem is when a user clicks on a result and it brings them to the exact location of the search query in the said book, I can not figure out how to run my highlight function to hightlight search query on the newly loaded page? New to Javascript here and I Hope I am clear on what I am trying to say. Here is a screen recording of the problem https://osaintilien55-gmail.tinytake.com/tt/NDU0MzA5OF8xNDQwMDE2Ng. I am using Lunr.js for search functionality and Mark.js for highlighting.

Here is the search function in my code

```
 //Add Event Listener to Search button
document.querySelector(".search-btn").addEventListener('click', searchFunction);

function searchFunction() {
    //Clear List
    document.querySelector(".results-wrapper").innerHTML = '';

    //Store query
    var searchQuery = document.querySelector("#search-id").value;

    // returns all documents which contain query
    var results = idx.search(searchQuery);

    var searchResults = results.forEach(function (entry) {

            documents.find(findText);

            function findText(doc) {
                let re = new RegExp(searchQuery, 'i');
                console.log(re);
                if (doc.name == entry.ref && doc.text.match(re)) {
                    //and if entry.text contains search query
                    //Break up string into sentences
                    var sentences = doc.text.match(/[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?]+/g);
                    console.log(doc.text);
                    console.log(sentences);
                    //              console.log("Page " + doc.page + " has the word " + searchQuery + " " + doc.text.search(re));
                    sentences.forEach(function (sentence) {
                        if (sentence.match(re)) {
                            var anchor = document.createElement('a');
                            anchor.className = 'anchorSearchResult'
                            anchor.href = doc.href;

                            //Create "div" element
                            var div = document.createElement('div');
                            div.className = 'div-test'

                            //Creates "h4" element for title
                            var h4 = document.createElement('h4');
                            var title = document.createTextNode(doc.name);
                            h4.className = 'title-results';

                            //Creates "p" element for sentence 
                            var textElement = document.createElement(p);
                            var searchResult = document.createTextNode(sentence);
                            textElement.className = "text-results";

                            //Creates "p" element for page 
                            var p = document.createElement('p');
                            var pageResult = document.createTextNode(doc.page);
                            p.className = "page-results";

                            h4.appendChild(title);
                            textElement.appendChild(searchResult);
                            p.appendChild(pageResult);

                            div.appendChild(h4)
                            div.appendChild(textElement)
                            div.appendChild(p)

                            anchor.appendChild(div)

                            document.querySelector(".results-wrapper").appendChild(anchor);

                            // Highlight Function
                            var instance = new Mark(document.querySelector(".results-wrapper"));
                            instance.mark(searchQuery, {
                                "element": "span",
                                "className": "highlight"
                            })
                        }
                    })
                }
            }

            
            //listen for Click event on searchResult list
            //onWindowsLoad run Highlight function
            //Highlight Function on search query word
            //Pass id Query Selector of search query
            //Highlight each instance of search query in Id's content
        }
        )}
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please.

Comment: Hey there well here is a fiddle version of my project https://jsfiddle.net/oiver55/naeyqLr1/. however in this example the results are not clickable because on fiddle I can't load other html pages of my project. Not sure exactly how to make a minimal example because my project is using Mark.js(for highlighting) and Lunr.js(search function).  However if it helps here is the code for my search function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use query strings. For example, the parameters of a function are stored in a query string called `params`.

You could read the query string. Then use `JSON.parse()` on the query string. Then run the function with the parsed array using the ES6 spread operator (`...`).

Example:

```js
var params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search) // Create a URLSearchParams object

function myFunction(a, b, c) {
    alert(a + ' ' + b + ' ' + c)
}

myFunction(...JSON.parse(params.get('params'))) // Run function with parsed params
```

[Example](https://example.smuppana060.repl.co/?params=%5B1,2,3%5D) - Try changing the query string named `params`. If you use strings, use double quotes since JSON requires double quotes, and we are using `JSON.parse()`

The query string has to be an array. For example:

```js
[1, 2, 3]
["One", "Two", "Five"]
[[], [], []]
```

Comment: Thanks this looks promising, Will give it a go!

Comment: Definitely, will do

Comment: Hey there I accepted the answer however I am  still trying to wrap my head around how this works, I have watched a couple of videos on query strings, but I still don't understand 100% how to get your example to work for me just yet, please take a look at this screenshot --->http://postimg.cc/RW5Zn4T0  Not sure if you could break it down for me a little bit more as to what exactly is happening and why I am getting and error.

Comment: You exact example here --> http://postimg.cc/nC7HxNtf
Sorry I am still in the learning phase although I have completed a JS course

Comment: @OliverSaintilien This is happening because the query string doesn't exist. Surround it with a try...catch block. Alternatively, you could just remove `...` and pass in an array (or `null`) and check if it is null with something like this (assuming the parsed JSON is stored in a parameter named `query`): `if (!query) { doSomething() }`. This also has more browser support.

Comment: @OliverSaintilien If there is no query string, it will return `null`.

Comment: hello there again, you have helped me before, If you can give any counsel on my new issue I would greatly appreciate it, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63765248/how-can-i-improve-my-search-function-logic-using-lunr-js