# How can I improve my search function Logic? Using Lunr.js

Tags: javascript, json, lunrjs

So I am using Lunr.js for my search function. Everything is working nice and dandy **BUT**, when I search certain keywords like "God" and "church" I get unacceptably long search times. I mean like, 30 secs and even beyond 1 min long. I'm sure it must be the logic I am using that is causing this, at least I think it is. The aim of my Search Function is to search the users input and return only the sentences where the key word is found along with the name of the book and the page where the searchQuery is found. My goal is to have a search function that can work offline. This is a Cordova project. I have commented everything so that you can follow the logic easily. Thank you for your time and input!

```
function searchFunction() {
//Clears results-wrapper Html element
document.querySelector(".results-wrapper").innerHTML = "";

//Store query in localDB
searchQuery = document.querySelector("#search-id").value;
localStorage.setItem("searchQuery", searchQuery);

//Returns from the index only the books which contains the query
var results = idx.search(searchQuery);

//Run through "results" and return all the text where the query is found
results.forEach(function (entry) {

//documents contains the database of all the books from my json file
documents.find(findSearchQuery);

//Searches only the text of the doc/books found in results variable 
function findSearchQuery(doc) {

  //searchQuery is the users input
  let re = new RegExp(searchQuery, "i");
  
  //if the book's name matches reference in "results"
  if (doc.name == entry.ref) {
    //And if the searchQuery is found in Books text
    if (doc.text.match(re)) {
      
      //Break up the block of text into sentences
      var sentences = doc.text.match(/[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?]+/g);

      sentences.forEach(function (sentence) {
        //Find the sentence inside the sentences array and return the one with the searchQuery
        //Populate HTML element "results-wrapper" with the results
        if (sentence.match(re)) {
          var anchor = document.createElement("a");
          anchor.className = "anchorSearchResult";
          anchor.href = doc.href;

          //Create "div" element
          var div = document.createElement("div");
          div.className = "div-test";

          //Creates "h4" element for title
          var h4 = document.createElement("h4");
          var title = document.createTextNode(doc.name);
          h4.className = "title-results";

          //Creates "p" element for sentence
          var textElement = document.createElement(p);
          var searchResult = document.createTextNode(sentence);
          textElement.className = "text-results";

          //Creates "p" element for page
          var p = document.createElement("p");
          var pageResult = document.createTextNode(doc.page);
          p.className = "page-results";

          h4.appendChild(title);
          textElement.appendChild(searchResult);
          p.appendChild(pageResult);

          div.appendChild(h4);
          div.appendChild(textElement);
          div.appendChild(p);

          anchor.appendChild(div);

          document.querySelector(".results-wrapper").appendChild(anchor);

          anchor.addEventListener("click", returnSearchResultId);

          function returnSearchResultId(e) {
            //store selectorId value of document
            localStorage.setItem("selectorId", doc.selectorId);
          }

          // Highlight Function
          var instance = new Mark(
            document.querySelector(".results-wrapper")
          );

          instance.mark(searchQuery, {
            element: "span",
            className: "highlight",
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
});
}
```

And here is just a snippet of my json file that is loaded in my "documents" variable.

```
[
  {
    "name": "Pre-Eleventh-Hour Extra",
    "year": "1941",
    "text": "Pre-\"Eleventh Hour\" Extra MYSTERY OF MYSTERIES EXPOSED!",
    "page": "1TR 2",
    "href": "tracks/tr1.html#page-2.subHeading",
    "selectorId": "#page-2\\.subHeading"
  },
  {
    "name": "Pre-Eleventh-Hour Extra",
    "year": "1941",
    "text": "In the interest of reaching every truth-seeking mind that desires to escape the path that leads to destruction of both body and soul, this tract will be distributed free of charge as long as this issue lasts.",
    "page": "1TR 2",
    "href": "tracks/tr1.html#page-2.1",
    "selectorId": "#page-2\\.1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Pre-Eleventh-Hour Extra",
    "year": "1941",
    "text": "PREFACE PERSONALLY WATCHING FOR EVERY RAY OF LIGHT.",
    "page": "1TR 3",
    "href": "tracks/tr1.html#page-3.preface",
    "selectorId": "#page-3\\.preface"
  },
  {
    "name": "Pre-Eleventh-Hour Extra",
    "year": "1941",
    "text": "One who entrusts to another the investigation of a message from the Lord, is making flesh his arm, and thus is foolishly acting as without a mind of his own. And  ”the mind that depends upon the judgment of others is certain, sooner or later, to be misled. ” -- Education, p. 231.",
    "page": "1TR 3",
    "href": "tracks/tr1.html#page-3.1",
    "selectorId": "#page-3\\.1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Pre-Eleventh-Hour Extra",
    "year": "1941",
    "text": "Similarly, one who allows prejudice to bar him from a candid investigation of anything new, coming in the name of the Lord, is unwittingly an infidel.",
    "page": "1TR 3",
    "href": "tracks/tr1.html#page-3.2",
    "selectorId": "#page-3\\.2"
  },
  {
    "name": "Pre-Eleventh-Hour Extra",
    "year": "1941",
    "text": "Likewise he who is satisfied with his present attainments in the Word of God, says in effect: \"I am rich, and increased with goods, and have need of nothing.",
    "page": "1TR 3",
    "href": "tracks/tr1.html#page-3.3",
    "selectorId": "#page-3\\.3"
  },
  {
    "name": "Pre-Eleventh-Hour Extra",
    "year": "1941",
    "text": "All these, in variously acting out the part which provoked the condemnation written against the Laodiceans, thereby fulfilling the prophecy which they ought not fulfill, are preparing themselves to be spued out (Rev. 3:14-18). And if they continue in their self-satisfied attitude that they have all the truth, and so have need of nothing more, they will spurn every new claimant to truth and toss the message into the discard because it comes through an unexpected channel. Certainly, then, were this tract not the unfolding of prophecy, the fact is inevitable that when the unfoldment did come, they would treat it in like manner, and consequently toss away their salvation!",
    "page": "1TR 3",
    "href": "tracks/tr1.html#page-3.4",
    "selectorId": "#page-3\\.4"
  },
  {
    "name": "Pre-Eleventh-Hour Extra",
    "year": "1941",
    "text": "Throughout the ages, all who have put their trust in the so-called wise men, and foremost Christians of the day, all reputedly godly men, have by these very ones been bereft of the crown of eternal life, as were the Jewish laity in the days of Christ because of their failing to assume full responsibility for their own salvation. Presumptuously trusting in the wisdom of their so-called \"great men,\" they declined to believe in Christ's words \"O Father, Lord of heaven and earth,...Thou hast hid these things from the wise and prudent, and hast revealed them unto babes.\" Matt. 11:25 \"Where is the wise? where is the scribe?...hath not God made foolish the wisdom of this world?\" 1 Cor 1:20.",
    "page": "1TR 4",
    "href": "tracks/tr1.html#page-4.1",
    "selectorId": "#page-4\\.1"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! It was the highlight functionality that I am getting from the Mark.js library that was causing the huge delay. After commenting it out, everything is lightening fast again.